# Spring boot properties: path to local project

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

**application.properties**
*path.repository=/repository*

When I execute the jar file from the project folder, the path defined in the application.properties works fine and it founds the folder.
But if I execute it from any other folder, the path is relative to this folder.

For example, path is spring/project/repository

- From project folder -> java -jar target/SNAPSHOT.jar  -> Repository path is spring/project/repository
- From spring folder -> java -jar project/target/SNAPSHOT.jar -> Repository path is spring/repository

I have tried classpath:/repository, but it only finds the file if it is in the src/main/resources

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320542/how-to-get-the-path-of-a-running-jar-file - In general I'd think about that requirement though: if it can be any path then use an absolute path, if it needs to be relative to the jar then think about whether it could be bundled with the jar.

Comment: try copying the repository with pom resource filter to your resource folder and call from classpath:/repository https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/2.0.0.M7/reference/html/howto-properties-and-configuration.html#howto-automatic-expansion-maven